# Label won't update even though the values are passed

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I am having some trouble with updating a label. In an Xaml.cs, I want to pass a value to another page, but not switching pages or so. Here is the code that I used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

using EscapeHaarlem.Models;
using EscapeHaarlem.Views;
using EscapeHaarlem.ViewModels;
using EscapeHaarlem.Services;

namespace EscapeHaarlem.Views
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
{
    ItemsViewModel viewModel;
    AboutPage aboutPage ;
    int Cost;
    public ItemsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
        aboutPage = new AboutPage();
    }

    async void AddItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new NewItemPage()));
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (viewModel.Items.Count == 0)
            viewModel.LoadItemsCommand.Execute(null);
    }

    private async void FlowListView_FlowItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.Item as Item;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        bool answer = await DisplayAlert(item.Text, item.Description, "Yes", "No");

        if (answer == true)
        {
            Cost = Cost + item.Cost;
            aboutPage.UpdatePusnihLabel(Cost);
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(new ItemDetailViewModel(item)));
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
        //ItemsPage.ListView.Item = null;
    }
}
}
```

Where the `AboutPage` is the page that needs the new value. After the display alert and the user pressed Ok, there should be a cost sent to the `AboutPage`. The value of `Cost` comes from a `MockDataStore` as example:

`new Item { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Item 1", Description="This is an item description.", Cost = 1},`

When I read the values with breakpoints in debugging mode all values are passed right. But when I want to display it in the `AboutPage` it won't change. This is the code from the Xaml.cs of the `AboutPage`:

```
    public void UpdatePusnihLabel(int Count)
    {
        lblCounter.Text = Count.ToString();
    }
```

Even here my values are right. But even if I try `lblCounter.Text = "Hello world";` it won't update the label.

This is the Xaml of the `AboutPage` label:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Label x:Name="lblCounter" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Rotation="270" FontSize="40" HorizontalOptions="Start" ></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Hope someone can tell me why my label won't update / show any text at all.

Comment: you are creating an instance of AboutPage but never navigate to it or otherwise display it

Comment: But this is in a ListView with two tabs? So won't it automaticly update? And when I call this function: UpdatePusnihLabel() does this not update the label?

Comment: if you already have an instance of AboutPage being displayed, creating a new instance in memory will not have any impact on the existing instance.  This is basic OOP

Comment: Ahhh alrright I think I start to get it, sorry just lerarning OOP. But how could it be fixed?

Comment: rather than directly modifying a value on another page, I'd use MessagingCenter to send a message to that page

Comment: Thanks that did solve it indeed!

Comment: @Xandervandenberg If you have solved this message, please post your solution to answer and mark it. It will help others who have similar issue.